# Why couldn't Noelle get cursed and her fight with Vanica

Tags: black-clover

In chapter 222/episode 127 of *Black Clover*, when Noelle was fighting Vanica, she outright mentioned her mother's Curse. And in an earlier turn, Dorothy went into Dorothy's Glamour World just so that the curse would not affect them so they could talk about it.

My only guess that I can have for an answer is that it might just be in the dub I haven't checked, but I want to see what anybody else thinks.

Comment: The dialogue does appear in the manga as well. I honestly have no idea how she isn’t cursed and why it isn’t talked upon in the *Black Clover* community.